# Excel - Return row header after searching for column header and a specific value in that column

Tags: excel-formula, lookup

I would like an Excel formula that returns the column header (value in column A) based on 2 conditions:

- Header Column Name (Country 1 in the example below)
- Specific Value in that Column (Yes in the example below)
  So in this case, If my Search Cell (A12) has the value "Country 1", I will get the result "Domain 5" in the Result Cell (B12).

As well, I should be able to add columns (yellow headers) without breaking the formula.

Full result table below:

- Country 1: Domain 1
- Country 2: Domain 3
- Country 3: Domain 2
- Country 4: Domain 6
- Country 5: Domain 4
- Country 6: Domain 5
- Country 7: Domain 8
- Country 8: Domain 7

I have created a google spreadsheet below with the example on the tab "Example".
What I am trying to achieve is visible on the tab "Check".
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FjHkCs8MoFy6w-mhcyufD1VEBX-r3Rdc98GoNcsKeC0/edit?usp=sharing

I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hand.

[Simplified example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K38md.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It's a double `MATCH` with an `INDEX` and an `OFFSET`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH("Yes",OFFSET($A$2:$A$4,0, MATCH(A7,$B$1:$D$1,0)),0))
```

[image]

Comment: I have just tried on a real use case and it looks like the formula you provided ajusted to that use case returns an error. I have a Google Spreadsheet test if that helps. Based on a value on a dropdown menu (Select Country) in one sheet (Check), I am trying to get values (Domain, Start Date, Status) from another sheet (List) where all the data is. Would you mind having a look: https://docs.google.com/a/cjorge-consulting.com/spreadsheets/d/1FjHkCs8MoFy6w-mhcyufD1VEBX-r3Rdc98GoNcsKeC0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have updated the question. Let me know if that is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In cell B7 use this formula:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH("Yes",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH($A$8,$A$1:$D$1))&":"&ADDRESS(4,MATCH($A$8,$A$1:$D$1)))))
```

Comment: Hi @a.celiwa, many thanks for this formula. I have updated the formula to be able to search on the cell A7 (instead of A8). It works brilliantly! =INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH("Yes",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH($A$7,$A$1:$D$1))&":"&ADDRESS(4,MATCH($A$7,$A$1:$D$1)))))

Comment: Hi @a.celiwa, I have just tried on a real use case and it looks like the formula you provided ajusted to that use case returns the wrong information. I have a Google Spreadsheet test if that helps. Based on a value on a dropdown menu (Select Country) in one sheet (Check), I am trying to get values (Domain, Start Date, Status) from another sheet (List) where all the data is. Would you mind having a look: https://docs.google.com/a/cjorge-consulting.com/spreadsheets/d/1FjHkCs8MoFy6w-mhcyufD1VEBX-r3Rdc98GoNcsKeC0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have updated the question. Let me know if that is clearer.